# Am I being Hacked? So many defferent ip's in router firewall logs

Tags: network, firewalls, router, network-scanners

My router dsl light was not stable; It keept disconnecting and connecting..So I logged into Router Homepage to check whats wrong and found there were so many different ip's in Router firewall logs I dont even know of..there was a log for every second..How do i stay secure..Im really scared, am I being hacked?

Comment: Is This Normal?..How do you guys protect your router..

Comment: As I said in my answer: it is normal but you don't need to worry about blocked attacks - only about attacks which succeeded (which you will very likely not see listed in your router). And my answer also contains several links to resources on this site which help you to secure your router.

Comment: Yes I have read your answer and Im following them and increasing security level.. **Thanks**

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately attackers scan the internet and are looking for vulnerable systems which they can exploit and then misuse to attack other systems - see for example [this information](https://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/featured/vpnfilter-botnet-has-hacked-500000-routers-reboot-and-patch-now/) about the VPNFilter botnet exploiting routers or [this information](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/06/widely-used-d-link-modemrouter-under-mass-attack-by-potent-iot-botnet/) about the Satori botnet infecting routers.

Thus, it is very likely that somebody is trying to attack your system. There is nothing you can do against somebody trying to attack you, but you can do something to make sure that the attacker does not succeed. This means especially to not use a router with known vulnerabilities or backdoors, with known default passwords or with weak passwords.

There are several information at this site which can help you with securing your router, for example [Best practice for home router configuration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101912/best-practice-for-home-router-configuration), [How to recommend a (more) secure router](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121527/how-to-recommend-a-more-secure-router), [Are consumer-grade routers any more or less vulnerable?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90309/are-consumer-grade-routers-any-more-or-less-vulnerable) or [How to secure a router/modem?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141506/how-to-secure-a-router-modem).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a DDOS attack but to be sure you should look at the logs and find out what is happening. But first check that your modem's firmware is updated and then change your admin password.

Also consider that maybe the attack is not **from outside** to **inside**; it is possible that some malicious software on your computer is the reason for the attack.